# How to use gmail API's Query? Setting property Q seems to be not effect

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using gmail API, all is working except query, the Q property.

```
// service.Users.Messages.List("me").Q = $"subject:(my search term)";
var response = service.Users.Messages.List("me").Execute();
```

gives back all messages, no matter if the preceding statement are commented out or executed.

I also examined the request with fiddler, and no traces of any query parameter or something in the GET request... no difference compared to queryless request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to have part of your request commented out for one.  Second optional parms need to be set in the manner below.

```
var request = service.Users.Messages.List("me");
request.Q = "subject:test";
var response = request.Execute();
```

To figuer out how to use the Q parm its best to test it in Gmail web app. The text you would send would be exactly the same

[image]

Comment: Many thanks.  Please read the OP "...no matter if the preceding statement are commented out or executed..." I wanted to stress, that debugging with Fiddler there is no difference between the commented out or .Q = "..." version.

Comment: ...but... I turned out, that using the request variable solves the my issue. probably every `service.Users.Messages.List("me")` creates a new request instance... so the correct way to get one, then modify its state, then execute

Comment: Testing with fiddler is not the same as using the .net client library this library was originally created more then ten years ago things where different back then.  Sadly the library has not been updated to take into account current best practices with C# and .net